# Очередь в ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, многопоточность

Насколько я понимаю, [принципы создания новых потоков в ThreadPoolExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35028992/4898850) следующие:

1. Если количество потоков (значение, возвращаемое методом `getPoolSize()`?) меньше, чем corePoolSize, создаётся новый поток для выполнения задания.
2. Если количество потоков равно (или больше чем) corePoolSize, задание добавляется в очередь.
3. Если очередь заполнена и количество потоков в пуле меньше, чем maxPoolSize, создаётся новый поток для выполнения задания.
4. Если очередь заполнена и количество потоков в пуле больше или равно maxPoolSize, задание отбрасывается.

Как тогда можно объяснить то, что строка логгера

```
logger.info("active executing tasks: " + threadPool.getActiveCount() + " current pool size: " + threadPool.getPoolSize() + " scheduled tasks: " + threadPool.getTaskCount() + " queue size: " + threadPool.getQueue().size());
```

выводит следующую строку

> active executing tasks: 18 current pool size: 100 scheduled tasks:
>   10034469 queue size: 0

а после добавления ещё одного задания строкой:

```
threadPool.execute(new SmsTask(smsIn));
```

очередь увеличивается?

> active executing tasks: 19 current pool size: 100 scheduled tasks:
>   10034470 queue size: 1

Правильно ли я понимаю, что `getActiveCount()` возвращает приблизительное количество выполняющихся в данный момент времени заданий, а `getPoolSize()` возвращает количество запущенных потоков? Т.е. если `getActiveCount()` возвращает 18, а `getPoolSize()` возвращает 100, то запущено 100 потоков, но 82 из них простаивают (находятся в состоянии idle)? Но если  82 потока простаивает, почему тогда новое задание добавляется в очередь, а не выполняется одним из этих idle-потоков?..

И чем может быть обусловлена большая разница между значениями, возвращаемыми методами `getActiveCount()` и `getPoolSize()` в `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Comment: Насколько получилось понять из быстрого просмотра по диагонали: pool size - это количество объектов типа worker, которые могут быть не привязаны к конкретным тредам; activeCount - количество воркеров, привязанных к треду. Это еще не отвечает на сам вопрос, но, похоже, что в данном случае цифры говорят просто о создании еще одного воркера и добавлении таска в очередь, если, конечно, это не какой-то артефакт от concurrent-выполнения.

Comment: а можно весь тест кейс посмотреть? непонятно какие параметры были при создании экзекьютора, а также неизвестно как были запущены предыдущие 10млн заданий.